# How to add To Script Manager reference to MS CDN JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, cdn, scriptmanager

I use C# and ASP.Net 4.
I have a Master Page, inside a Script Manager with `EnableCdn="True"` so I can load automatically all ASP.NET Ajax Library from MS CDN Servers.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="uxScriptManagerMasterPage" runat="server" 
        EnableCdn="True">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

I need also to include in my Master Page JQuery library. At the moment I'm using the following element in the Header of the page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I would like to know if there is any properierty for ScriptManager that would allow me to load all Ms Ajax library plus Jquery from MS CDN using ScriptManager.

I had a look at CdnPath property but I'm not able to make it work.

DO you have any ideas? Are you able to provide me a sample of code? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ScriptResourceMapping section of this 
[Asp.Net 4.0 ScriptManager improvements](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2009/11/23/asp-net-4-0-scriptmanager-improvements.aspx) post shows a solution for this problem.